# Storybooks webpack config: loader not configured

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I was having a working webpack config for storybooks. Then I realized that during start of storybooks some files could not be bundled from my application. Of course I do not want the app to be bundled but only my shared ui. So I was trying to add the include path in my webpack config:

```
// https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/typescript-config/
const path = require('path');

module.exports = ({ config }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
            },
            {
                loader: require.resolve('react-docgen-typescript-loader'),
            }
            ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './base/shared-ui'),
        },
        {
        test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                },
                {
                    loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                },
                {
                    loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
                }
            ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './base/shared-ui'),
        });
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx', '.scss');
    return config;
};
```

However, now I do get the following error:

```
WARNING in ./base/shared-ui/components/src/buttons/Buttons.stories.tsx 22:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| stories.add(
|     'Toast',
>     () => <ToastsShowcase/>,
|     { info: {
|         text: `
 @ ./base/shared-ui sync \.stories\.tsx$ ./components/src/buttons/Buttons.stories.tsx
 @ ./.storybook/config.ts
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./.storybook/config.ts (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
```